# How to mint audio NFT

Tags: web3.js, nft, solana-wallet-adapter, react, arweave

I want to mint audio and image nft at the same time. Using Web3.js and Arweave.
I am uploading audio and image to arweave and then nft metadata with those links for audio and image. It is successful.

Then I am minting that metadata with web3.js. The problem is, in my Phantom wallet collectibles I only see the image. I can listen the audio at solscan.io. Is there a way to listen the audio also in phantom wallet collectibles?
I also do not mint my nft on Solsea or any similar platforms. Is that necessary?

```
  async function onClick() {
       if (!wallet.publicKey) throw new WalletNotConnectedError();
       connection.getBalance(wallet.publicKey).then((bal) => {
           console.log(bal / LAMPORTS_PER_SOL, "lamp sol");
       });
       if (metadataRequest === null) return;
       
       const metadataTransaction = await arweave.createTransaction(
           { data: metadataRequest },
           arweaveKey
       );
       metadataTransaction.addTag('Content-Type', 'application/json');
       await arweave.transactions.sign(metadataTransaction, arweaveKey);

       let response = await arweave.transactions.post(metadataTransaction);

       const mintNFTResponse = await actions.mintNFT({
           connection,
           wallet: wallet,
           uri: `https://arweave.net/${metadataTransaction.id}`,
           maxSupply: 1
       }).catch(e => console.error(e,));
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this post re: audio NFT metadata. I'd recommend you adhere to the standard if you are not already.
[How to make the json for an mp3 Metaplex programmable NFT](https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/5825/how-to-make-the-json-for-an-mp3-metaplex-programmable-nft/5827#5827)

Here's Phantom's documentation around how they display NFTs: https://docs.phantom.app/best-practices/tokens/collectibles-nfts-and-semi-fungibles
If you're not getting expected results from phantom, search your mint address in [Solana Explorer](https://explorer.solana.com/), [SolScan](https://solscan.io/), and [Solana FM](https://solana.fm/) to make sure that your metadata is actually rendering correctly on these sites. If the audio is not available on any of them, it's likely a metadata issue. If it's available on those sites but not in Phantom, you might check their discord to see if they have any recommendations specific to their platform.

Comment: I doubt Phantom supporting the playable audio within the wallet, but attaching audio url to  "animation_url" in metadata object helped and now you can listen to audio within the wallet. Thank you a lot!